# XHTML lang and xml:lang value

Tags: xhtml, lang

When specifying the lang or xml:lang for the `<html>` tag do I need to use `en-us` or `en` is enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more specific you can be, the better, but "en" is enough.